# Can't open ports (windows server 2016 ec2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, windows-server-2016

I tried opening port 80, 7171, 7172 on my Windows Server (AWS EC2).

I allowed the inbound rules in security groups in ec2 management console and in the windows firewall inside the instance.

But, only port 80 got opened, any ideas guys?

I've previously done the same with an Ubuntu instance and it worked just fine then - which leads me to think it has to be something inside the windows server.

I've also tried disabling the firewall.

Comment: Is there a process/service running that's listening on those ports?

Comment: There's your answer then. If there's no process or service running that's listening on those ports then there's nothing to connect to.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no process or service running that's listening on those ports then there's nothing to connect to.

You need to have a process or service running and listening on those ports.